# How can trajectories be images of solutions and a partition of the domain?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently learning about trajectories (also called orbits) of autonomous odes (let x'= f(x)), and I find it quite paradoxical that trajectories are at the same time the image of a solution for a specific initial value, but as shown by a theorem they also induce a partition over the domain of f.
What haunts me, is that when I look at a specific phase portrait that the trajectories don't fill the entire domain but as a partition of such they actually should. When you look at the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPp8m.jpg) the circular trajectories are a part of the domain but aren't a partition on it.

Comment: Is it any more "mysterious" then plotting $y = x^2$, which divides the space into values above and below the curve?

Comment: If you plotted every single curve, the screen would be full. But of course, we can only plot finitely many if we want to see how the solutions actually look (rather than a black screen)

Answer (score 1):

We are given the system

$$\begin{align} x' &= y \\ y' &= -x \end{align}$$

We can solve it using many methods (substitution, eigenvalues/eigenvectors...numerically)

$$x(t) = c_1 \cos (t)+c_2 \sin (t) \\ y(t) =\ c_2 \cos (t)-c_1 \sin (t)$$

We can plot a phase portrait and then superimpose some numerical solutions onto it and get

[image]

Notice that we have an infinite number of possibilities and can fill the entire phase portrait so it looks like one giant blob, but that wouldn't help us see that each solution is a circle.

The phase portrait has just enough information to help us qualitatively tell the behaviors of the system and it's solutions being circles.

We could however keep adding more and more solutions, but then the plot starts looking like

[image]

Comment: Yes of course we can't plot the images of all solutions, but the book I've got this example from says, that here we've got only five trajectories (not infinite), and each trajectory is the image of the solution for a given initial value. How is it possible that we have only five images for infinitely many initial values?

Comment: They are just saying that they used five ICs and only show 5 solution curves. Want more curves, provide more ICs. You can provide an infinite number of ICs and generate infinite curves as the phase portrait is trying to show global behaviors. However, for each IC, you only have a single solution curve. Clear?

Comment: The number of trajectories (5 in our case) isn't arbitrary, it's determined by the given autonomous ode.  I think the general problem is, that we talk about different things, you mean solutions, but trajectories aren't solutions, you can have infinitely many solutions but everyone of them belongs to one of few trajectories (the number of them is fixed, the number of solutions you plot is arbitrary). So the trajectories induce a partition on the set of all solutions/initial conditions.

Comment: Not correct, trajectories are solutions. Why and where are you getting this from?

Comment: Unfortunately the book I've got that example from is in german ("Gewöhnliche Differentialgleichungen" by Bernd Aulbach). However a book which also defines trajectories (here they are called orbits) as images of solutions is "Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems" by Gerald Teschl, which is in English.

Comment: Maybe look for a different sources like: http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am34/Mathematica/ch2/portrait.html, https://gereshes.com/2019/03/04/an-introduction-to-phase-portraits/, https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/qualitative-behavior-phase-portraits/, https://canvas.harvard.edu/courses/18236/files/2463519/download?download_frd=1

Comment: Also, see the bottom of page 40, where it start as In Figure 3.1: https://booksite.elsevier.com/samplechapters/9780123820105/Chatper_3.pdf

Comment: @NikiWeber: Perhaps, try an experiment. Pick a bunch of ICs, do a numerical solution, do a parametric plot of those solutions on top of each other. What do you notice?